# How to plot a graph of the error on the parameters of the classifier

Tags: python, graph, machine-learning, classification

Trying to find the best parametres of a classifier.

Following my code:

```
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, random_state=42)
param = {"criterion":["gini", "entropy"], "max_features":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10,      15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, "log2", "auto"],
         "max_depth":[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64], "class_weight":[None, "balanced"]}
cv = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param, scoring="accuracy", n_jobs = -1, cv=kf)
cv.fit(X_train, y_train);
print("Best score (accuracy): ", cv.best_score_)
print("Best params: ", cv.best_params_)
print("Score on X_test: ", accuracy_score(y_test, cv.predict(X_test)))
```

But I want plot a graph of the mean accureacy of classifier on the parameters of the classifier.

Please help me out, 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `GridSearchCV` is doing exhaustive search, you might have a matrix of results i.e. each parameter combination associated with accuracy. You may then chose what you want to plot from this

Hopefully, such a matrix exists, and can be retrieved using `GridSearchCV`'s attribute `cv_results_`

From [GridSearchCV's doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):
[image]

i.e. you can do:

```
result_matrix = cv.cv_results_
```

Happy plotting
pltrdy